# How to Enable USB in Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 in Oracle Virtual Box. I would like to access USB flash drive in the Virtual Box. I just found this link

https://www.tecmint.com/enable-usb-in-virtualbox/

I have downloaded and installed the Extension Pack as described in the link above and also added the USB flash drive in the Virtual Box settings. Now I am not able to run the command to allow the user "peter" which is the only user in Ubuntu 16.04.4 machine.

```
peter@peter:~$ sudo usermod -aG vboxusers peter
[sudo] password for peter:
usermod: group 'vboxusers' does not exist
```

and perhaps this is the reason that I am not able to see the drive with this command.

```
$ sudo lsblk
```

How to mount the USB flash drive in Ubuntu 16.04.4 ?

[image]

Comment: I am running this command on Guest OS which is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It has to be ran in the Host OS.

Comment: I have Windows 10 host machine. How to run this command in Windows 10.

Comment: It doesn't look like it is needed:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/usb-support.html  All you should have to do in your VitualBox app is make sure that you enable USB support in the Settings -> USB for the VM you are trying to run.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why the Enable USB Controller is disable and USB Device Filter is there in which I can add the external USB drive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116532/discussion-between-engr-john-and-terrance).

Comment: This really is about Windows support since your VirtualBox is installed into Windows.  The settings are grayed out because the VM is running.  Stop the VM, change the settings to USB 2.0 and you should be fine after that.  Also, mouse over the Exclamation point at the bottom and see what your invalid settings are and fix those too.

Comment: Hi, Now it appear in Virtual Box.   peter@peter:~$ sudo lsblk
[sudo] password for peter: 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465,8G  0 part /media/peter/TOSHIBA EXT
How to mount and access data in this drive ? The type is "HPFS/NTFS/exFAT"

Comment: It's already mounted at `/media/peter/TOSHIBA EXT`

Comment: Yes I found it. Thanks